# Best way to pass session information to another domain to track conversions?

Tags: php, api, session

Building a web application that is 90% API-based, meaning it will be hosted on the client's website (eg clientdomain.com). When API calls are made, we are creating and storing a session ID on the client's domain, and we store all the stats on their activity while a visitor browses their site.

But there's one part of our application that is hosted on our servers, because it has to be secure (eg client.ourdomain.com). Visitors will click a link from the client's website to ours.

What's the best way to somehow tell the application on our domain that this is an active session with session id XXXXXXX? I've thought of a few options:

- Check sessions table for IP and timestamp within a certain range. Obviously this would not be a good option because some large groups and organizations use the same IP.
- Pass the session ID as a GET variable, downside is these links may be shared or saved for later use.
- Pass as POST var using a form button
- Use some kind of redirect variable dynamically created that is only good for a small time frame (i.e. 10 or 30 minutes) and then deleted

Am I missing a possible solution?

Our ultimate goal is to track a visitor through goal completion so we can show conversion rate, bounce rate, etc. To do that we absolutely have to match up a visitor from clientdomain.com to client.ourdomain.com.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first option is the answer, SessionID + IP = Unique.

User A and User B may have the same IP but their session id is different.

Comment: The first option is vulnerable to session hijacking.

Answer (score 0):

Fifth:

```
<a href="http://clientdomain.com/redirect-to-secure.php">go</a>
```

redirect-to-secure.php:

```
header('Location: http://client.ourdomain.com/?clientSession=' . session_id());
```

On client.ourdomain.com, if you detect `clientSession` GET param, save it to session and redirect to page without `clientSession`. This way browser won't remember this url.